# Android Draw a circle and detect bound of image

Tags: android, image, canvas

Now ,  i have the circle  and  image on the canvas

Ping-pong board and Ping-pong ball (draw by drawCircle)

The position of ball will depend on the accelerator

is possible to detect whether the ball the outside the board or not?

Or, i need to draw the board Programmatically without using the image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called 'Collision Detection'. A technique used in game programming where the boundaries (area that defines where the object can be hit) are and then if an object enters those positions.

You can do this simply by saying that the boundaries are anything in the height / width of the image on the canvas. But I suspect that in your game you will want a subsection of that.

You will need to define a related object to your image that holds the 'Collision Boundary'. On a 2D game that will be the starting X,Y and then the height and width. While on a 3D game you will also need to store the Z position.

This is probably quite confusing to start with but I found you this little guide that explains it in more detail than I have space for here:

http://www.kilobolt.com/day-4-collision-detection-part-1.html

Let me know if you have any questions and the game sounds exciting!

Comment: Thanks,JodiMiddleton,
just forget my idea， if i create some block on the canvas( like maze), the ball should not touch the block util the ball moved to the purpose position.  How can  calculate the arc of ball is touch the block or not  with pure coding??

Comment: You will need to look at game physics here.You will need to set the balls speed, deceleration and pull from gravity. Basically in a 2D game as you move the ball either to the left or right you also decrease the height slightly until it hits a bat or the table. Doing this by hand is hard works so you might want to check out some game engines that have solutions for this kind of stuff. Here is a list that Intel have collated: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/05/14/eight-popular-open-source-android-game-engines

Comment: It sounds like you want to try and avoid coding where possible. Never a bad to be honest. If you want to get your product out quicker maybe a program like this http://gamesalad.com/ which makes it really easy to make IoS and Android games?